# How to access methods of a concrete class in a Generic class in Java without casting

Tags: java, generics, vert.x

I have a method that publishes List of events in Kafka:-

```
public class EventProducerService<T>{
private Future<Void> publish(List<T> events) {
        final String topicPublishURL = Url + String.format(PUBLISH_EVENT_URI_TEMPLATE, this.topic);

        final String body;
        try {
            body = JacksonUtils.toJson(events);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return Future.failedFuture(e);
        }

        return httpRequester.postAsync(httpClientWrapper.getOrCreateClient(), topicPublishURL, body);
    }
}
```

and this class is defined using :-

```
new EventProducerService(httpClientWrapper, tokensFacade, WRITE_URL,
            topic, BUFFER_SIZE, vertx, metricRegistry);
```

I want to send the event info to a tracking service after a successful publish. The T in List events can have different classes with their own unique methods. I want to track one of them **OrderTrackingInfoEvent**.

So, How do I access methods of **TrackingInfoEvent** inside the above publish method?

Please note that casting cannot be used.

Please help. I am new to Java.

I was told to specify some publisher handler on EventProducerService, something that is called after httpRequester.postAsync(...), with the future returned, and the list of events.

and the handler would be specified when constructing the EventProducerService instance.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a generic handler would work for sure. When you construct the `EventProducerService` instance, you know the generic type and in the handler you can specify what you want to do with it without modifying the EventProducerService logic. Another idea is to make T implement an interface that includes all the methods that you want to access from EventProducerService.

`public class EventProducerService<T extends MyInterface>{...`

The downside of the idea is that all the T types must implement the interface methods that might not be relevant to all the concrete classes.

All in all, I would recommend the idea of a generic handler. It comes from functional programming principles and is much more flexible than narrowing the generic type by implementing an interface.

```
public interface MyHandler<T> {
    void handle(Future<Void> f, List<T> events);
}

public class EventProducerService<T>{
MyHandler<T> handler;
private Future<Void> publish(List<T> events) {
        final String topicPublishURL = Url + String.format(PUBLISH_EVENT_URI_TEMPLATE, this.topic);

        final String body;
        try {
            body = JacksonUtils.toJson(events);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return Future.failedFuture(e);
        }

        Future<Void> f = httpRequester.postAsync(httpClientWrapper.getOrCreateClient(), topicPublishURL, body);
        handler.handle(f, events);
        return f;
    }
}
```

and you can pass the handler as a Java 8+ function to the constructor.

```
new EventProducerService(httpClientWrapper, tokensFacade, WRITE_URL,
            topic, BUFFER_SIZE, vertx, metricRegistry, (f, events) -> {
            // your code
            });
```

Comment: Thank you.
Is there a way to do this without using the interface MyHandler?

Comment: No problem! Actually no, the standard way of creating a function in Java 8+ is through a single-method interface.